# Why does log.debug() not log when the level is set to logging.DEBUG?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I was expecting that the following code would output both log lines

```
import logging

log = logging.getLogger('hello')
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
print(log.getEffectiveLevel())
log.debug('debug log')
log.critical('critical log')
```

The output is

```
10
critical log
```

The level is correctly set to `10` (which [corresponds to `DEBUG`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging-levels)) and despite this `log.debug('debug log')` does not output anything - why?

Comment: you mean print the log to `stdout` or `stderr`?

Comment: @MiguelTrejo: why would there be a difference? debug messages would be printed elsewhere than critical ones? And this elsewhere would not be impacted by `.setLevel()`?

Comment: You only set the level on the logger itself, not the initial handler that will be used to print the log message to standard error. Handlers and loggers have separate levels, so that (for instance) a single logger can write debugging messages to the console, but only serious errors to an SMTP handler to notify someone of a problem that needs to be addressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't configured the logging system, so it's still using the defaults (level WARN for the root logger).

https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig says `basicConfig`

> Does basic configuration for the logging system by creating a
> StreamHandler with a default Formatter and adding it to the root
> logger.

Configuring the logging system with `basicConfig` first will create a handler and formatter that your logger will use:

```
logging.basicConfig()
log = logging.getLogger('hello')
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
print(log.getEffectiveLevel())
log.debug('debug log')
log.critical('critical log')
```

Outputs:

```
10
DEBUG:hello:debug log
CRITICAL:hello:critical log
```

In [Logger.callHandlers](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1666), each handler compares the log record's level with its level. If there aren't any handlers, it will use the [default](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1221) of WARNING.

Comment: Thanks - so in my case my `log` output is still driven by the default `WARNING` level despite being effectively set to `DEBUG`?

Comment: Yes, you set your logger to DEBUG, but it's not connected to a handler (there aren't any yet). Try `print('handlers=', logging.getLogger().handlers)` with and without `basicConfig`. The docs on Handler (https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Handler) show that the `__init__(level=NOTSET)` method takes a level parameter.

Comment: But if there are no handlers, how could the critical level message be displayed? Because it was handled by the root level logger? (and despite having its own logger somehow bubbled up to the root logger?)

Comment: If there aren't any, it uses the default level of WARNING: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1672

Comment: @kielni I tried your suggestion and it works, but the `handlers` property of the logger still seems to be an empty list

Comment: @WoJ the reason why something is displayed is that when no handlers are configured, there is an internal "handler of last resort" which is used, and which has a level of `WARNING`. Documented here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html?highlight=resort#logging.lastResort

Answer (score 1):

With a `StreamHandler` it will

> sends logging output to streams such as sys.stdout, sys.stderr or any file-like object"

according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html)

```
import logging 
import sys

# Initialize Logger and set Level to DEBUG
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Initialize a Handler to print to stdout
handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)

# Format Handler output
logFormatter = logging.Formatter(
    "%(asctime)s %(message)s", datefmt="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"
)
handler.setFormatter(logFormatter)

# Set Handler Level to DEBUG
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(handler)

logger.debug('Debug Info')
>>> 09/19/2020 09:01:00 PM Debug Info
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add stream handler

```
import logging

log = logging.getLogger('hello')
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# # Create a file handler to store the logs
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('test.log')
log.addHandler(file_handler)

# # Send output to terminal
stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
log.addHandler(stream_handler)

log.debug('debug log')
```